# Which files should I modify to get rid of the unpleasant buzzing alerts?

Tags: rimworld

In RimWorld, there are many events that are announced not only with a notification on the right side of the screen, but also with a gratingly-loud buzzing noise that I could do without.  For example:

- Heat wave
- Mental break
- Eclipse
- Zzzt (short in the electrical system)

I'd like to either silence these alerts completely or else replace them with something less unpleasant (such as the "ding" when a new colonist joins).

I've found the SoundDef files that I'd need to modify to do something about this (pictured below).  But there are quite a lot of them.

I assume silencing the alerts is as simple as setting their volume to 0.  Can anyone help me figure out how to find them?

[image: RimWorld SoundDef XML files]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally figured this out while playing around with the Dev Tools.

- Enable Dev Tools in the Settings menu
- At the top of the screen, click the third icon from the left in the floating menu (two overlapping squares)
- Click `SoundDefs`, `No package loaded`, `UI_Oneshots_Misc`

The sound you're referring to is called `LetterArrive_BadUrgent`. You could delete it by pressing the `X` (I didn't try it, so that may cause errors), or click it, then adjust the volume using the `volumeRange` setting.

Note, once you click on the sound name in the menu, you can listen to the sound by clicking the triangle play button at the top of the window that comes up.

Comment: I tried this, and it's working great!  That play button was an excellent tip.  I did need to make sure to click Save after the modifications, or they didn't persist to the next time I ran.  And when I saved, on the next run I got an error about the XML file needed `Defs` instead of `DefPackage` at the root.  I made that change in a text editor, and now none of my red envelopes show up with nerve-jangling buzzes anymore.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kyralessa Glad you got it working. So the dev tools corrupted one of the folder names and needed to be fixed? If you give some more details, I'll add a bit in my answer.

Comment: It wasn't the folder name; it was the root element in the XML.  The error was that it had `<DefPackage>` as the XML root element, and it needed to have `<Defs>` instead.  It was just a matter of replacing DefPackage with Defs in the opening and closing root elements.

Comment: Thanks again, Carcigenicate.  It's amazing how much more tranquil an experience the game becomes without the buzzers.

Comment: @Kyralessa Np. I actually like the buzzers, as it keeps me on my toes. To each their own though. And I'll try to get a note added in regarding your first comment. Times be tight lately though.

Comment: Does this still work?  In the most recent version of RimWorld, I can't find SoundDefs anymore.

Comment: @Kyralessa I have no idea. They changed a lot in the new version, so they may have renamed it or something. I'll check next time I play.